# How do I use union all with multiple tables using sql in Hadoop?

Tags: sql, hadoop, sas, union

I am trying to 'union all' multiple tables in SAS (using sql) within Hadoop. I found threads on union all and was able to get it to run within my local sas user, however the output was too large and SAS crashed, so I have to put the datasets that I then want to union in Hadoop and then union them. This is where I am having issues with the syntax. The code is below. I usually use the beginning and ending part of the code for connecting to Hadoop.

```
Proc SQL noerrorstop; 
Connect to HADOOP (server='X' port=X); 
Execute (set X) by HADOOP; 
Execute (drop Table X.CV_All) by HADOOP; 
Execute (create Table X.CV_All as
SELECT cv.* 
INTO: CV_All
FROM (SELECT * FROM X.CV_Dec
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM X.CV_Jan
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM X.CV_Feb) cv;
) by HADOOP;
DISCONNECT FROM HADOOP;
quit;
```

I receive the following error: ERROR: Execute error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:86 missing EOF at ':' near 'INTO'

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hadoop uses `create table as` rather than `select into`.  Does this work?

```
CREATE TABLE cv_all as
    SELECT cv.* 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM X.CV_Dec
          UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM X.CV_Jan
          UNION ALL
          SELECT * FROM X.CV_Feb
         ) cv;
```

Some comments.  First, I don't think the subquery is necessary for the statement, but I'm leaving it in.

Second, you are missing the point of Hadoop, by having multiple tables with the same format.  You should have a single table with a date column.  You can partition by the data by the date.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. To give some background: I was provided with the three separate tables with data for each month. I added a column to each for month and populated it (Dec, Jan, Feb). So now I am trying to pull them together into one table. To your point, I will then be able to query the aggregate table and partition by month.

Comment: I tried the changes you suggested and it's working! Thanks for the tip!